# pandas read_csv working only as root user

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas, anaconda

I am reading a csv file using pandas. It works fine if I run script as root user. But when I try to run it with different user it does not read data and gives:

```
error :  KeyError: 'no item named 0'
```

it appears at:

```
dt = pd.read_csv('rt.csv', header=None).fillna('').set_index(0).to_dict()[1]
```

Btw, I am working on Ubuntu 12.02 and using anaconda, which is installed in root user and other user as well (which is giving error) 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You like have different pandas versions installed as user and root.
I get the same error with version 0.16.2 when I use the wrong delimiter. 
Have a look at your data in `rt.csv`.

For example, this would work for a whitespace-delimited file:

```
dt = pd.read_csv('rt.csv', header=None,
                 delim_whitespace=True).fillna('').set_index(0).to_dict()[1]
```

Check the file and adapt the delimiter accordingly.

Comment: Yes, You are right. There were different Pandas versions installed. I have updated to latest one and it's working fine now. Thanks for your help @mike-müller

Comment: Great that it worked. BTW, you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) an answer if it solves your problem.